# DevOps not showing changes for a git pull request

Tags: git, azure-devops

I suspect the fact that I'm using DevOps isn't relevant - I guess this would be the case for any git repo. Here's my scenario:

1. I created a branch from `main` called `main2`
2. I changed `main2`, submitted a PR in DevOps, it was approved and the source branch deleted
3. I then changed `main2` again locally, and issued the following command to update it remotely:

   `git push -u origin main2`
4. This created the remote branch, so I created a PR, however DevOps says there are no changes between `main2` and `main`

My guess is that this is because `main2` is newly created from local, and therefore not tracking main - is this the case? If so, how can I force it to track main - or can't I?

Comment: How many *new* commits did you add to `main2` in step 3? Can you see those commits with `git log origin/main2` ? (I assume you cannot.) Can you see them locally with `git log main2` ?